# Photoshop - Layers losing transparency when merging

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency

I'm working on multiple layers on Photoshop (CS6). Some of the layers have different layer styles like multiply. When I merge the layers together I seem to lose the transparency on some of the image, how can I sort this please?

[image: this is before merging]

[image: and this is after]

Comment: Please attach the snapshot of your file before and after merging the Image.
then I'll be able to give you a specific answer

Comment: And make sure to merge two transparent layers

Comment: Updated my question :)

Comment: You either have to make the white parts actually transparent or flatten the whole document. When you merge stuff with blend mode like multiply, you gotta merge it with its background, so it retains the look.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're merging together. If you're going to merge the layers, I'm assuming you don't want to edit the layer later on.

Right-click the transparent layer, select *Convert to Smart Object*. Then right-click it again and select *Rasterize Layer*. Now you can merge this layer with others like usual.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge layers, then don't use layer styles like multiply, overlay and so on.

To solve you problem set a normal state to those layers.
Select the Background Eraser Tool
[image]

And set it as on this image:
[image]

Set the foreground color you want to protect (like that light-blue) and after that click on white space on your canvas. That should erase all pixels you don't want to see. Try different foreground colors for different results.

After that merge your layers.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having this issue because you are using some artistic filters in your project But

The simplest thing you can do to get rid of this problem is:

Select the layers you want to merge.Right click and select Convert to smartobject then restarize the smartobject layer